# VB6 Tabs Not Showing on Form

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I recently downloaded VB6 to open a .VBP file that I am in the process of converting to VB2010. My goal is to run the program on VB6 so I can step through the code line-by-line in order to debug the program I am writing from scratch in VB2010.

The program, which runs off a Virtual Machine, has a starup form that looks like this:

[image: Form on virtual machine]

However, when I view the startup form on VB6, I see this:
[image: Form on VB6]

As you can see, the tab pages are missing. When I run the code, the debugger breaks at the first line that involves the tab pages (FrontWeights, etc are all names of a few tab pages ***(names of GRIDS, not tab pages)***, and the debugger breaks on "FrontWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000"):

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
  Screen.MousePointer = 11

  Width = 10680
  Height = 6816
  FrontWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000
  FrontWeights.ColWidth(2) = 1109
  FrontWeights.ColWidth(3) = 1109
  FrontWeights.ColWidth(4) = 1109
  For I = 1 To 100
    FrontWeights.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  FrontWeights.Row = 0
  FrontWeights.Col = 1
  FrontWeights.Text = "Description"
  FrontWeights.Col = 2
  FrontWeights.Text = "Quantity"
  FrontWeights.Col = 3
  FrontWeights.Text = "Weight (lbs)"
  FrontWeights.Col = 4
  FrontWeights.Text = "Offset (in)"

  BogieWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000
  BogieWeights.ColWidth(2) = 1109
  BogieWeights.ColWidth(3) = 1109
  BogieWeights.ColWidth(4) = 1109
  For I = 1 To 100
    BogieWeights.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  BogieWeights.Row = 0
  BogieWeights.Col = 1
  BogieWeights.Text = "Description"
  BogieWeights.Col = 2
  BogieWeights.Text = "Quantity"
  BogieWeights.Col = 3
  BogieWeights.Text = "Weight (lbs)"
  BogieWeights.Col = 4
  BogieWeights.Text = "Offset (in)"

  CenterWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000
  CenterWeights.ColWidth(2) = 1109
  CenterWeights.ColWidth(3) = 1109
  CenterWeights.ColWidth(4) = 1109
  For I = 1 To 100
    CenterWeights.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  CenterWeights.Row = 0
  CenterWeights.Col = 1
  CenterWeights.Text = "Description"
  CenterWeights.Col = 2
  CenterWeights.Text = "Quantity"
  CenterWeights.Col = 3
  CenterWeights.Text = "Weight (lbs)"
  CenterWeights.Col = 4
  CenterWeights.Text = "Offset (in)"

  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(1) = 3005
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(2) = 795
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(3) = 795
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(4) = 795
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(5) = 795
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(6) = 795
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(7) = 795
  InternalPipingGrid.ColWidth(8) = 795
  For I = 1 To 100
    InternalPipingGrid.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  InternalPipingGrid.Row = 0
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 1
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "Description"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 2
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "Lbs/Ft"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 3
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "Gal/Ft"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 4
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "Passes"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 5
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "X Front"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 6
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "Y Front"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 7
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "X Rear"
  InternalPipingGrid.Col = 8
  InternalPipingGrid.Text = "Y Rear"

  KingPinWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000
  KingPinWeights.ColWidth(2) = 1109
  KingPinWeights.ColWidth(3) = 1109
  KingPinWeights.ColWidth(4) = 1109
  For I = 1 To 100
    KingPinWeights.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  KingPinWeights.Row = 0
  KingPinWeights.Col = 1
  KingPinWeights.Text = "Description"
  KingPinWeights.Col = 2
  KingPinWeights.Text = "Quantity"
  KingPinWeights.Col = 3
  KingPinWeights.Text = "Weight (lbs)"
  KingPinWeights.Col = 4
  KingPinWeights.Text = "Offset (in)"

  LandingLegWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000
  LandingLegWeights.ColWidth(2) = 1109
  LandingLegWeights.ColWidth(3) = 1109
  LandingLegWeights.ColWidth(4) = 1109
  For I = 1 To 100
    LandingLegWeights.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  LandingLegWeights.Row = 0
  LandingLegWeights.Col = 1
  LandingLegWeights.Text = "Description"
  LandingLegWeights.Col = 2
  LandingLegWeights.Text = "Quantity"
  LandingLegWeights.Col = 3
  LandingLegWeights.Text = "Weight (lbs)"
  LandingLegWeights.Col = 4
  LandingLegWeights.Text = "Offset (in)"

  RearWeights.ColWidth(1) = 4280 + 1000
  RearWeights.ColWidth(2) = 1109
  RearWeights.ColWidth(3) = 1109
  RearWeights.ColWidth(4) = 1109
  For I = 1 To 100
    RearWeights.AddItem Str$(I), I
  Next I
  RearWeights.Row = 0
  RearWeights.Col = 1
  RearWeights.Text = "Description"
  RearWeights.Col = 2
  RearWeights.Text = "Quantity"
  RearWeights.Col = 3
  RearWeights.Text = "Weight (lbs)"
  RearWeights.Col = 4
  RearWeights.Text = "Offset (in)"

  Screen.MousePointer = 0
End Sub
```

Any help on how I can fix this issue? FYI - this is a work project, so I would be hesitant to share/upload files.

EDIT: text of project file:

```
Type=Exe
Module=MODULE11; TransWgt.Bas
Form=TankSize.frm
Form=Properti.frm
Form=Bulkhead.frm
Form=PrintOut.frm
Form=Drawing.frm
Object={6B7E6392-850A-101B-AFC0-4210102A8DA7}#1.3#0; COMCTL32.OCX
Object={00028C01-0000-0000-0000-000000000046}#1.0#0; DBGRID32.OCX
Reference=*\G{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#2.0#0#C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb#Standard OLE Types
Reference=*\G{00025E01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#4.0#0#C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL#Microsoft DAO 3.0 Object Library
Form=InputData.Frm
Startup="InputDataForm"
HelpFile=""
Title="Transport Weight Analysis"
ExeName32="TransWgt.Exe"
Command32=""
Name="TransportWeightAnalysis"
HelpContextID="0"
CompatibleMode="0"
MajorVer=1
MinorVer=0
RevisionVer=0
AutoIncrementVer=0
ServerSupportFiles=0
VersionComments="This is a pre-release version of this program."
VersionCompanyName="E.D. Etnyre & Co."
VersionFileDescription="Program for calculating weight distributions of any transport."
CompilationType=0
OptimizationType=0
FavorPentiumPro(tm)=0
CodeViewDebugInfo=0
NoAliasing=0
BoundsCheck=0
OverflowCheck=0
FlPointCheck=0
FDIVCheck=0
UnroundedFP=0
StartMode=0
Unattended=0
Retained=0
ThreadPerObject=0
MaxNumberOfThreads=1
```

**EDIT 2:** Changed VM form to what the entire screen shows (ie, also a menu)

***EDIT 3:*** There was a .CLS file that VB6 was somehow not able to load initially. I manually added not. Now when I run, my error says 'Compiler Error: Invalid outside procedure"

Comment: The marbles in my head thinks that isn't the standard TabStrip control that came with VB6.  Looks like a 3rd party product.  The code you posted looks like it's populating a grid.

Comment: Shows the TEXT contents of the VBP file.

Comment: Text is added. Also, I was able to use the VB2008 Upgrade Wizard to upgrade the VB6 .VBP file. There are a ton of syntax errors to it, but the tab control is also not present, if that helps

Comment: @LarsTech - the code is meant to populate Grids. On the VM, there is one Grid on multiple Tab Pages.

Comment: What does this mean: `When I run the code, the debugger breaks at the first line that involves the tab pages`.  Is there an exception?  What happens when that line is reached?

Comment: @larstech sorry for the confusing - the exact message is "Compile Error: Method or data member not found"     It resembles a warning textbox. When I click on OK, the debugger does not head, and the line "Private Sub Form_Load() is highlighted yellow with an yellow arrow

Comment: Again, sorry for the confusion - FrontWeights, etc are all names of Grids. There is one grid in multiple tab pages

Comment: my assumption is that line of code is unable to run because it is not able to create/edit (not sure which) the GRID found in that TAB PAGE because the TAB PAGE does not exist

Comment: The Tab Control in the image comes from TABCTL32.OCX, titled "Microsoft Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0".  I don't see the reference for that in the VBP file you included.

Comment: @LarsTech any idea on how the Virtual Machine is able to include the Tab Pages?

Comment: Couldn't tell ya.  The virtual server has the control, doesn't look like your version does.

Comment: @LarsTech any idea on a solution?

Comment: Maybe show the frm file contents for the form in question.  It would show what the form is trying to build.

Comment: it doesn't look that you are launching the VB6 IDE on the same VM where the original software is installed. Do you have an install package?

Comment: That is correct: the program is running off a VM that is a shortcut added to my Desktop. I am in the process of manually converting its code (found in .frm files, .bas files, etc) into VB2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody other than you can say what's happened, but - just guessing - the reference to the SSTabs contained in the TABCTL32.OCX has been deleted (or replaced with a reference to the mscomctl.ocx, because of the TabStrip...?) and the project has been saved.

At least, i can tell you why you don't see any other control on the Form other than those of the first Tab:

Below you see a Form with three Tabs, with each one control inside:

[image]

the way SSTabs works, is by shifting the controls to the left outside the form to hide it:

```
      Text1.Left = 480           Text2.Left = -74520           Text3.Left = -74520
```

Open the `.frm` file with Notepad, the controls shall be there, but you just can't see it in the IDE.

At the end, depending how critical your project is, i believe you have two options:

- restore by hand in the `.frm` the SSTabs and then in the IDE, place the controls on a different container
- change by hand in the `.frm` file the controls position by shifting the Left coords by 75000

As isn't clear to me which VB6 version do you exactly installed, i'm adding below for your convenience a complete `.frm.`file where you can see the stored structure of the SSTabs. Add the Tabs you need.

```
VERSION 5.00
Object = "{BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}#1.1#0"; "TABCTL32.OCX"
Begin VB.Form Form1 
   Caption         =   "Form1"
   ClientHeight    =   2835
   ClientLeft      =   60
   ClientTop       =   345
   ClientWidth     =   3615
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   ScaleHeight     =   2835
   ScaleWidth      =   3615
   StartUpPosition =   3  'Windows Default
   Begin TabDlg.SSTab SSTab1 
      Height          =   2535
      Left            =   120
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   120
      Width           =   3285
      _ExtentX        =   5794
      _ExtentY        =   4471
      _Version        =   393216
      TabHeight       =   520
      TabCaption(0)   =   "Tab 0"
      TabPicture(0)   =   "FormTabs.frx":0000
      Tab(0).ControlEnabled=   -1  'True
      Tab(0).Control(0)=   "Text1"
      Tab(0).Control(0).Enabled=   0   'False
      Tab(0).ControlCount=   1
      TabCaption(1)   =   "Tab 1"
      TabPicture(1)   =   "FormTabs.frx":001C
      Tab(1).ControlEnabled=   0   'False
      Tab(1).Control(0)=   "Text2"
      Tab(1).Control(0).Enabled=   0   'False
      Tab(1).ControlCount=   1
      TabCaption(2)   =   "Tab 2"
      TabPicture(2)   =   "FormTabs.frx":0038
      Tab(2).ControlEnabled=   0   'False
      Tab(2).Control(0)=   "Text3"
      Tab(2).Control(0).Enabled=   0   'False
      Tab(2).ControlCount=   1
      Begin VB.TextBox Text3 
         Height          =   375
         Left            =   -74520
         TabIndex        =   3
         Text            =   "Text3"
         Top             =   1680
         Width           =   2295
      End
      Begin VB.TextBox Text2 
         Height          =   375
         Left            =   -74520
         TabIndex        =   2
         Text            =   "Text2"
         Top             =   1080
         Width           =   2295
      End
      Begin VB.TextBox Text1 
         Height          =   375
         Left            =   480
         TabIndex        =   1
         Text            =   "Text1"
         Top             =   720
         Width           =   2295
      End
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "Form1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False

End Sub
```

The same reference shall be added to the `.vbp`file, at the very top, near the others:

```
Object={BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}#1.1#0; TABCTL32.OCX
```

Comment: I will try this out!

Comment: so, I searched "tab" in the folder the .VBP file is located in and found the following file: TABCTL32.OCX. This was in a folder titled "SetupWiz"

Comment: I have VB6 Express

Comment: @TylerBraun:: after your last comment, i believe you have another chance: you should install the true VB6 (or VB from Visual Studio 6). This will install all files you need, then, reopen the original project,  that shall be enough ... SSTabs are simply not supported in recent versions of Visual Studio

Comment: seems like a much easier solution - I'll try that out.